# PySpark: Using an existing Spark DataFrame's Schema on new Spark DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

In Python, I have an existing Spark DataFrame that includes 135~ columns, called `sc_df1`. I also have a Pandas DataFrame with the exact same columns that I want to convert to a Spark DataFrame and then `unionByName` the two Spark DataFrames. i.e., `sc_df1.unionByName(sc_df2)`.

Does anyone know how to use the schema of `sc_df1` when converting the Pandas DataFrame to a Spark DataFrame, so that the two Spark DataFrames will have the same schema when unioning?

I know this isn't working, but below is essentially what I'm trying to do:

```
sc_df2 = sc.createDataFrame(df2, schema = sc_df1.dtypes)
```

Comment: Does using `sc_df1.schema` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **`spark.createDataFrame()`** by passing **pandas_dataframe** with **schema** of `sc_df1` dataframe.

**`Example:`**

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([("a",1),("b",2)],["id","name"])

#converting to pandas df
pandas_df=df.toPandas()

print(type(pandas_df))
#<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

#converting back to pysparkdf by passing df schema
spark_df=spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df,schema=df.schema)

print(type(spark_df))
#<class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>

spark_df.show()
#+---+----+
#| id|name|
#+---+----+
#|  a|   1|
#|  b|   2|
#+---+----+


#union both dataframes
df.union(spark_df).show()
#+---+----+
#| id|name|
#+---+----+
#|  a|   1|
#|  b|   2|
#|  a|   1|
#|  b|   2|
#+---+----+
```